# Trouble shooting socket.io and EBS

Tags: socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

**Scenario**: I have a node.js application, that uses socket.io for communication. If I run it locally it works great. I will then deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. If I run it there and use it myself, it works great. Even a few users, works fine. However, once I start to get lots of users, the application (a chat app), becomes unresponsive. Sometimes messages will send, sometimes they won't, sometimes they are delayed.

I know I have read that EBS doesn't support web sockets. However, it seems to be fine with a few users. I am not quite sure how to test if socket.io is really the problem or not.

Here are a couple logs that i get from running the app.

> "GET
> /socket.io/?token=MSAxNDYyMzAyNzM4NTc2IDU2OTJiNDQzZmYxYzdjYzNiOTE5MjMxZSAxODRmNmQ4NGIzNGQ0OWUzOWZiMWUwYTI1ZDhhYWVjOA%3D%3D&EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LD32u37
> HTTP/1.1" 200 101
>
> "GET
> /socket.io/?token=MSAxNDYyMzAyNzM4NTc2IDU2OTJiNDQzZmYxYzdjYzNiOTE5MjMxZSAxODRmNmQ4NGIzNGQ0OWUzOWZiMWUwYTI1ZDhhYWVjOA%3D%3D&EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=DZof5F5PCmmy26eEAAAA
> HTTP/1.1" 400 45

These two logs are from just single use by myself.

I've tried running this app on two different EBS instances, Load Balanced and Single Instance. I get the same type of logs on both.

I am not quite sure how to troubleshoot this, and how to diagnose if its socket.io the problem, or something else.

Any thoughts?

Comment: any chance you running this on a load balanced env with more than one instance? If that's the case, you're missing the sticky session configuration from EB

Comment: @Tal thanks for your response. I do realize i need to implement Sticky sessions now. Can you advise the best way to actually test this? I was attempting to use redis, but i can't figure out the best way to actually test whether the sticky sessions are working or not. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I advise you'd enable sticky session to ensure a client is always served by the same server. This should rid you of the mentioned errors.
Sticky session is enabled at the beanstalk console under configuration=>Load Balancer=>Session stickiness.
To test this you can simply use a network inspector such as the one in Chrome developer tools. You should be able to see that the requests you send to the server contain the cookie AWSELB, with the exact same value every time. This validates that you hit the same server in beanstalk. Also, your errors should be gone.